# Algorithm that makes the sum of three lines excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need an algorithm  that makes sum of  three cells and put it in the third cell, and repeats the same thing for the rest of the line.

[The table i want to have algorithm  with code  vba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfnKC.png)

```
With ws    
    i = .Range("AC9").End(xlDown).Row
    cumul = 0

    .Range("AF9").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("AC9:AC" & i))    
End With
```

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: i use this code But does not work  'With ws

    i = .Range("AC9").End(xlDown).Row
    cumul = 0
    
    .Range("AF9").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("AC9:AC" & i))

End With'

Comment: show us your code here @Houyam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Sub sums()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("mySheetname") '<--| change "mySheetname" to your actual sheet name
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| change "A" references to your actual "Poid_CFA" column index
            cell.Offset(, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cell.Resize(, 3))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```